# Meta Keywords & Description show on every post

Tags: php, html, wordpress, wordpress-theming, meta

Below is the PHP code of the WordPress traction theme. I want to show my keywords and description on every post/pages as shown on home page. How do I do this?

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.1//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml11/DTD/xhtml11.dtd">
<html xml:lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<?php if ( is_front_page() ) : ?>
<title><?php bloginfo( 'name' ); ?></title>
<meta name="description" content="<?php if ( is_single() ) {
single_post_title('', true); 
} else {
bloginfo('name'); echo " - "; bloginfo('description');
}
?>" />
<meta name="keywords" content="mediafire, free movies, download movies, movies 
mediafire, online movies, download mediafire movies, movies online, hindi movies, 
bollywood movies, english movies, small movies, high quality, small size, free 
download, download, download links" />
<meta http-equiv="author" content="M.Naeem Riaz" />
<?php elseif ( is_404() ) : ?>
<title><?php _e( 'Page Not Found |', 'traction' ); ?> | <?php bloginfo( 'name' ); 
?></title>
<?php elseif ( is_search() ) : ?>
<title><?php printf(__ ("Search results for '%s'", "traction"),  
attribute_escape(get_search_query())); ?> | <?php bloginfo( 'name' ); ?></title>
<?php else : ?>
<title><?php wp_title($sep = '' ); ?> | <?php bloginfo( 'name' );?></title>
<?php endif; ?>
<!-- Basic Meta Data -->
<meta name="Copyright" content="Design is copyright <?php echo date( 'Y' ); ?> The  
Theme Foundry" />
<meta http-equiv="imagetoolbar" content="no" />
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="<?php bloginfo( 'html_type' ); ?>; 
charset=<?php bloginfo( 'charset' ); ?>" />
<?php if ((is_single() || is_category() || is_page() || is_home()) && (!is_paged())) : 
else : ?>
<meta name="robots" content="noindex,follow" />
<?php endif; ?>

<!-- Favicon -->
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="<?php bloginfo( 'stylesheet_directory' ); ?>/images
/favicon.ico" />

<!--Stylesheets-->
<?php if ( ($traction->colorScheme() != 'default' ) ) { ?>
    <link href="<?php bloginfo( 'stylesheet_directory' ); ?>/stylesheets/<?php 
echo $traction->colorScheme(); ?>.css" type="text/css" media="screen" rel="stylesheet" 
/>
<?php } ?>
<link href="<?php bloginfo( 'stylesheet_url' ); ?>" type="text/css" media="screen" 
rel="stylesheet" />
<!--[if lt IE 8]>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="<?php 
bloginfo( 'template_url' ); ?>/stylesheets/ie.css" />
<![endif]-->

<!--WordPress-->
<link rel="alternate" type="application/rss+xml" title="<?php bloginfo( 'name' ); 
?> RSS Feed" href="<?php bloginfo( 'rss2_url' ); ?>" />
<link rel="pingback" href="<?php bloginfo( 'pingback_url' ); ?>" />

<!--WP Hooks-->
<?php if ( is_singular() ) wp_enqueue_script( 'comment-reply' ); ?>
<?php wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery' ); ?>
<?php wp_head(); ?>

<!--Scripts-->
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php bloginfo( 'template_url' ); 
 ?>/javascripts/traction.js"></script>
<?php if ( is_front_page() && ($traction->sliderState() != '' ) ) { ?>
    <!--Slider-->
    <?php
        $autoStart = 0;
        $slidespeed = 300;
        $fadespeed = 200;
        if ($traction->sliderSpeed() != '' ) $slidespeed = 
 $traction->sliderSpeed();
        if ($traction->sliderFade() != '' ) $fadespeed = 
$traction->sliderFade();
        if ($traction->sliderStart() == 'true' ) $autoStart = 
$traction->sliderDelay(); else $autoStart = 0;
    ?>
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
        jQuery(function(){
            jQuery("#feature").loopedSlider({
                containerClick: false,
                autoStart: <?php echo $autoStart; ?>,
                slidespeed: <?php echo $slidespeed; ?>,
                fadespeed: <?php echo $fadespeed; ?>,
                autoHeight: 1
            });
        });
    </script>
<?php } ?>

</head>

<body <?php body_class($traction->colorScheme()); ?>>
<div class="skip-content"><a href="#content"><?php _e( 'Skip to content', 
'traction' ); ?></a></div>
<div id="pg-nav-bg">
    <div class="wrapper clear">
        <div id="pg-nav">
            <ul class="nav">
                <?php if ($traction->hideHome() !== 'true' ) : ?>
                    <li class="page_item <?php if 
(is_front_page()) echo( 'current_page_item' );?>"><a href="<?php bloginfo( 'url' ); 
?>"><?php _e( 'Home', 'traction' ); ?></a></li>
                <?php endif; ?>
                <?php if ($traction->hidePages() !== 'true' ) : ?>
                    <?php wp_list_pages( 'title_li=&exclude='. 
$traction->excludedPages()); ?>
                <?php endif; ?>
            </ul>
        </div><!--end pg-nav-->
    </div><!--end wrapper-->
</div><!--end page-navigation-bg-->
<div class="wrapper big">
    <div id="header" class="clear">
        <?php if ($traction->logoState() == 'true' ) : ?>
            <div class="logo logo-img">
                <a href="<?php bloginfo( 'url' ); ?>"><img 
src="<?php bloginfo( 'stylesheet_directory' ); ?>/images/<?php echo 
$traction->logoName(); ?>" alt="<?php if ($traction->logoAlt() !== '' ) echo 
$traction->logoAlt(); else echo bloginfo( 'name' ); ?>"/></a>
                <?php if ($traction->logoTagline() == 'true' ) { ?>
                    <div id="description">
                        <?php bloginfo( 'description' ); ?>
                    </div><!--end description-->
                <?php } ?>
            </div><!--end logo-->
        <?php else : ?>
            <div class="logo">
                <?php if (is_home()) echo( '<h1 id="title">' ); 
 else echo( '<div id="title">' );?><a href="<?php bloginfo( 'url' ); ?>"><?php 
 bloginfo( 'name' ); ?></a><?php if (is_home()) echo( '</h1>' ); else echo( '</div>' 
 );?>
                    <div id="description">
                        <?php bloginfo( 'description' ); ?>
                    </div><!--end description-->
            </div><!--end logo-->
        <?php endif; ?>
        <?php if ($traction->bannerState() != '' ) { ?>
            <div class="banner">
                <a href="<?php if ($traction->bannerUrl() != '' ) 
echo $traction->bannerUrl(); else echo "#"; ?>"><img class="alignleft" src="<?php 
bloginfo( 'stylesheet_directory' ); ?>/images/ads/<?php if ($traction->bannerImage() != 
'' ) echo $traction->bannerImage(); else echo "468_ad.png"; ?>" width="468" 
height="60" alt="<?php if ($traction->bannerAlt() != '' ) echo $traction->bannerAlt(); 

else echo bloginfo( 'name' ); ?>" /></a>
            </div>
        <?php } ?>
        <div id="cat-nav" class="clear">
            <ul class="nav">
                <?php if ($traction->hideCategories() != 'true' ) 
: ?>
                    <?php wp_list_categories( 'title_li=&
exclude=' . $traction->excludedCategories()); ?>
                <?php endif; ?>
            </ul>
        </div><!--end cat-nav-->
    </div><!--end header-->
    <?php if (($traction->sliderState() != '' ) && is_front_page() && 
!is_paged() ) { ?>
        <?php if (is_file(STYLESHEETPATH . '/featured.php' )) 
include(STYLESHEETPATH . '/featured.php' ); else include(TEMPLATEPATH . '/featured.php' 
); ?>
<?php } ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want metatags for every post/page just take out metas for description and keywords of the global condition `is_front_page`. Your code for `head` section regarding to metatags could be as follows (look at the comments for each type metatag):

```
<!-- Title -->
<?php if ( is_front_page() ) : ?>
<title><?php bloginfo( 'name' ); ?></title>

<?php elseif ( is_404() ) : ?>
<title><?php _e( 'Page Not Found |', 'traction' ); ?> | <?php bloginfo( 'name' ); 
?></title>

<?php elseif ( is_search() ) : ?>
<title><?php printf(__ ("Search results for '%s'", "traction"),  
attribute_escape(get_search_query())); ?> | <?php bloginfo( 'name' ); ?></title>
<?php else : ?>
<title><?php wp_title($sep = '' ); ?> | <?php bloginfo( 'name' );?></title>
<?php endif; ?>

<!-- Description / Keywords -->
<meta name="description" content="<?php if ( is_single() ) {
single_post_title('', true); 
} else {
bloginfo('name'); echo " - "; bloginfo('description');
}
?>" />
<meta name="keywords" content="mediafire, free movies, download movies, movies 
mediafire, online movies, download mediafire movies, movies online, hindi movies, 
bollywood movies, english movies, small movies, high quality, small size, free 
download, download, download links" />
<meta http-equiv="author" content="M.Naeem Riaz" />

<!-- Basic Meta Data -->
<meta name="Copyright" content="Design is copyright <?php echo date( 'Y' ); ?> The  
Theme Foundry" />
<meta http-equiv="imagetoolbar" content="no" />
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="<?php bloginfo( 'html_type' ); ?>; 
charset=<?php bloginfo( 'charset' ); ?>" />
<?php if ((is_single() || is_category() || is_page() || is_home()) && (!is_paged())) : 
else : ?>
<meta name="robots" content="noindex,follow" />
```